# Correct way to analyse python data held in dictionary lists

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

Just getting into python programming and I just about understand lists and dictionaries.  But now I'm way out of my depth and my google-fu has let me down.

I've written a little program that reads scores form a csv file

```
def main():
  with open('test_data.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    test_database = []
    for row in reader:
        test_database.append(dict(username=row['username'],
                             subject=row['subject'],
                             dificulty=row['dificulty'],
                             answers=row['answers'],
                             questions=row['questions'],     
                             percentage=row['percentage'],     
                             grade=row['grade']))    
    csvfile.close()
  print(test_database)
```

and it uses the following csv file
[test_data.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N54ex.jpg)

```
username,subject,dificulty,answers,questions,percentage,grade
ian47,History,Hard,1,5,20.0,D
ian47,Computer Science,Medium,5,5,75.0,B
```

and generates the following data

```
[{'username': 'ian47', 'dificulty': 'Hard', 'questions': '5', 'grade': 'D', 'percentage': '20.0', 'answers': '1', 'subject': 'History'}, {'username': 'ian47', 'dificulty': 'Medium', 'questions': '5', 'grade': 'B', 'percentage': '75.0', 'answers': '5', 'subject': 'Computer Science'}]
```

My question is how is the best way to manipulate this data, I really like the way it formats the data and makes it easy to understand but now I'm having difficulty retrieving and manipulating this data.

I'm looking to do the following:-

- Display all the results for a single person
- Display the Highest/lowest/average scores for a single person per subject per difficulty
- Display the highest score for each subject and the person who got it

If anybody can help and point me in the right direction for one or two of these questions I'm sure I will be able to work it out for the rest

Answer (score 0):

This question is probably too broad, but if I were you I would look into Pandas. With pd.read_csv you'll have something very much like (wrote original as `t.csv`):

```
>>> import pandas as pd 
>>> t = pd.read_csv('t.csv')
>>> t
  username           subject dificulty  answers  questions  percentage grade
0    ian47           History      Hard        1          5        20.0     D
1    ian47  Computer Science    Medium        5          5        75.0     B
>>> t[t['grade'] == 'B']
  username           subject dificulty  answers  questions  percentage grade
1    ian47  Computer Science    Medium        5          5        75.0     B
>>> t.at[0, 'username'] = 'frank'
>>> t
  username           subject dificulty  answers  questions  percentage grade
0    frank           History      Hard        1          5        20.0     D
1    ian47  Computer Science    Medium        5          5        75.0     B
>>> t['percentage'].max()
75.0
>>> t.groupby(['subject', 'username'])['percentage'].max()
subject           username
Computer Science  ian47       75.0
History           ian47       20.0
Name: percentage, dtype: float64
>>> 
>>> t.to_csv('t.csv')
```

Then, when I check the contents of `t.csv`, I get:

```
username,subject,dificulty,answers,questions,percentage,grade
ian47,History,Hard,1,5,20.0,D
ian47,Computer Science,Medium,5,5,75.0,B
```